# Do you unlock anything if you are a gold-medal virtual chef?

Tags: cooking-mama-4-kitchen-magic

I know that you get stars for bonuses that unlock various outfits/scenery changes for Mama and the kitchen, but do you get anything for getting gold on a recipe, or for getting gold on all of the recipes?

It might just be the glory of knowing I am a good virtual cook, which would be okay, I suppose, but is there a further point to the gold medals?